# Automatically scroll to a particular element Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, scroll, widget

In my widget I display a list of tasks for the week, each of them are organised by day:

Here is what my widget looks like without any of the tasks loaded :

[image]

Here is when I load the tasks:

[image]

Tasks of the monday appear below monday, tasks for tuesday below tuesday. The thing is when there is a lot of tasks as above the user doesn't have a global vision of the tasks for each day, he need to scroll down.

So what I would like to do is to directly scroll to the today's day.

I encapsulated the widget in a SingleChildScrollView in which I defined a controller :

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                        controller: scrollController,
```

I used the **jumpTo** and **animateTo** functions of the controller to make the automatic scroll, I called them in the initState as below :

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      scrollController.animateTo(1000.0, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000), curve: Curves.ease);
      //scrollController.jumpTo(500.0);
    });
  }
```

It works well when I don't load the tasks and use only hardcoded data. But when I load the tasks it doesn't work, there is a delay in when the widget is build and when the data is loaded, so that when the data is finally loaded the scrolling motion as already be "spent" and doesn't happen.

NB: For each day of the week I use 1 FutureBuilder that return a filtered list of tasks.

I would like to know how I could fix that.

Also, whether for animateTo or jumpTo you provide an offset, I would like for it to scroll directly to a particular widget (for example if we are thursday, to the Text("Thursday") widget) because the number of tasks will be variable so I can't directly know the value of the offset needed to land to a particular day.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You should do the async work before building the SingleChildScrollView. Perhaps work with only one FutureBuilder that retrieves the information for the whole week, the retrieved data can be restructured into a List<List<TaskModel>> and the FutureBuilder would return your WeekOverviewWidget in which you input the List<List<TaskModel>> such that the SingleChildScrollView can get all the data at build-time. And have a look at https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list

Comment: have you tried `setState` inside `addPostFrameCallback` method.

Comment: Yes, doesn't work.